# after refresh how to check whether the checkbox is checked before refreshed in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

how to make a checkbox remain unchanged whether it is checked or unchecked though the page is refreshed manually or automatically?
Can you please provide code in your answer?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function checkFirstVisit() {
  if(document.cookie.indexOf('mycookie')==-1) {
    // cookie doesn't exist, create it now
    document.cookie = 'mycookie=1';
  }
  else {
    // not first visit, so alert
    alert("refreshed");
    checked();
  }
}

function checked()
{
var ins1=document.getElementById("id");

if(ins1.checked)
    ins1.checked=true;

}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="checkFirstVisit()">
<input type="checkbox" id="id" >
<input type="checkbox" id="id" >
<input type="checkbox" id="id">
<input type="checkbox" id="id">
<input type="checkbox" id="id">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code ?

Comment: If I check the checkbox and then refresh the page the checkbox is unchecked...but I want it remain check..

Comment: Then you need to get parameters on form submit and then set them as request attribute and check if set then check/uncheck accrodingly